# Adding elements to a char** argument

Tags: pointers, char

So, I have a function that takes as one of its parameters a `char**` variable, and I have to add to this variable pointer to certain strings. How could I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what "add" means in "add to this variable pointer" and I don't know what "certain strings" means. You need to describe the requirements better and/or provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `char**` type as a list of strings. It is actually a pointer to the start of an array of pointers to the starts of arrays of chars.

That been said, it is unclear what you want to do.

But say you wanted to get the second char of the third string of some `char** x`, you would use either:

```
*(*(x+3)+2)
```

Or

```
x[3] [2]
```

Of course you need to watch for segmentation fault, i.e. Know the length of your arrays.